# How to graph dates on X axis in Rickshaw

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I have a set of data for dates. What value should I provide the X axis values? How do I make Rickshaw display the X data values as dates?

I looked around the docs and examples and cannot find anything.

Comment: Did you see [this example](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html)?

Comment: Yes. I have looked at the examples. I have now figured out that my axis were not showing nicely because I did not include the css. But I still have not figured out how to provide the date data and render it as dates. The examples generate random data and I do not know which format it is in.

Comment: I guess the easiest thing to do would be to print the variable that holds the data to the debug console so you can have a look at it.

Comment: Have you looked at "axes and tick marks" section in rickshaw documentation? http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/

Comment: You may be able to use d3 format function, like this: var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m-%d"));

Comment: I know it has been a while, but have you decided on an answer to this question?

Comment: First comment link gives 404 use [this](https://tech.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html) instead.

Answer (score 13):

I've just started using Rickshaw and was in the exact situation.

But, before I go any further, Rickshaw documentation is virtually nonexistent which is very upsetting because the performance of Rickshaw compared to other JS graphing libraries is outstanding.

The best way to find examples is to dig into the source code and example code on their github page try to make sense of things (not the way documentation should be).

That being said, let's try and build a strong base of questions/answers here on StackOverflow!

So, back to the question :) It looks like you've already found your own solution to the question, but I'll provide my solution as well.

Rather than using `Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time`, I've used `Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X` and set the `tickFormat` accordingly.

```
var data = [ { x: TIME_SINCE_EPOCH_IN_SECONDS, y: VALUE }, 
             { x: NEXT_TIME_SINCE_EPOCH_IN_SECONDS, y: NEXT_VALUE } ]

var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
  graph: graph,
  tickFormat: function(x){
                return new Date(x * 1000).toLocaleTimeString();
              }
})
xAxis.render();
```

**toLocaleTimeString()** can be any of the Javascript date functions, such as **toLocaleString()**, **toLocaleDateString()**, **toTimeString()**, or **toUTCString()**. Obviously, because the *tickFormat* takes a function as an argument one can supply their own formatter.

Koliber, I'd be interested to understand your answer if you could provide more detail as well.

Comment: The function name in the sample code is incorrectly provided as 'toLocateString' when it should be 'toLocaleString'. Couldn't make the edit as 'edits must be 6 characters' :/

Comment: I should also have said thank you, as this solution was just what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Lars' reply, I found by default Rickshaw is calling

```
 .toUTCString(x.value*1000) //(just ctrl+F to find where =) ).
```

In my case, I saw different time label on X between Graphite and Rickshaw for this reason, and it works beautifully once I changed it to

```
 .toLocaleString(x.value*1000).
```

Plus, you may need modify this in two places : Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time and the ...HoverDetails

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out that the X axis values should be epoch time values. Then, using the code from the examples I was able to show a proper time scale.

I still have a problem because I would like to show the tick marks on weeks on the X axis. However, setting timeUnit to 'week' causes JavaScript errors. It works with other time units though.

Comment: Did you solve this week problem? I have exactly the same one.

Comment: I have a similar problem, and have been unable to find out a solution. My data are minute data covering part of  the same day (from 8:45:00 to 13:15:00). Would you be kind to share your piece of code, please?

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me. What worked with angularjs was:

`'x' : d3.time.format.iso.parse(date).getTime(), 'y' : 10`